# Prove that $f(x;y;z)=(x+y+z;x-y-2xz)$ can be resolve for $(x,y)=\phi(z)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, implicit-function-theorem

Let be $f(x;y;z)=(x+y+z;x-y-2xz)$ a function, prove that it can be resolve for $(x,y)=\phi(z)$ close to $z=0$. Find explicitly $\phi(z)$

I'm very lost for this problem, first I thought it could be resolved withe the Implicit  Function Theorem but it's for functions from $\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to solve $f=0$.  For that purpose solve
$$\begin{align}
x+y+z&=0\\
x-y-2yz&=0
\end{align}$$
for $x$ and $y$.  Substituting $y=-x-z$ in the second equation gives
$$x=\frac{z}{2z-2},$$
from which
$$y=\frac{z}{2z-2}-z$$
is easily computed.